# rabbitMQ federation VS ActiveMQ Master/Slave

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am trying to set up cluster of brokers,  which should have same feature like rabbitMQ cluster, but over WAN (my machines are in different locations),  so rabbitMQ cluster does not work.

I am looking to alternatives,  rabbitMQ federation  is just backup the messages in the downstream,  can not make sure they have exactly the same messages available at any time  (downstream still keeps the old messages already consumed in the upstream)

how about ActiveMQ  Master/Slave,  I have found : 
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html

"queues and topics are all replicated between each broker in the cluster (so often to a master and maybe a single slave). So each broker in the cluster has exactly the same messages available at any time so if a master fails, clients failover to a slave and you don't loose a message."

My concern is that if it can automatically update to make sure  Master/Slave always have the same messages,  which means the consumed messages in Master will also disappear in Slaves.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ has various clustering features.

First there is High Availability - "Master/Slave". The idea is that several physical servers act as a single logical ActiveMQ broker. If one goes down, another takes it place without losing data. You can do that by sharing the message store (shared file system or shared JDBC), or you could setup a [replicated cluster](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html), which replicates read/writes to the master down to all slaves (you need three+ servers). ActiveMQ is using LevelDB and Apache Zookeeper to achieve this.

The other format of cluster available in ActiveMQ is to be able to distribute load and separate security over several logical brokers. Brokers are then connected in a network of brokers. Messages are by default passed around to the broker with available consumers for that message. However, there is a rich toolbox of features in ActiveMQ to tweak a network of brokers to do things as always send a copy of a message to specific broker etc. It takes some messing with the more advanced features though (static network connectors and queue mirroring, maybe more).

Maybe there is a better way to solve your requirements, which is not really specified in the question?